# I want get user info, but i can't make sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Help me please, I have problem: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as countPosts,' at line 1

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, users.email, users.avatar, users.about, users.birthday, users.gender, users.firstName, users.lastName, users.single, users.statement, users.mainTimelineId, media.preview as avatarMediaPreview, media.file as avatarMediaFile, media.fileType as avatarMediaFileType
              (select COUNT(id) from posts where posts.userId=121) as countPosts,
              (select COUNT(id) from followers where toId=121) as countFollowers,
              (select COUNT(id) from followers where fromId=121) as countFollowing,
              (select COUNT(id) from connections where fromId=121 or toId=121) as countConnections,
              (select id from followers where fromId=121 and toId=121) as followId
              FROM users
              LEFT JOIN media ON media.id = users.avatarMediaId 
              WHERE users.id=121
```

Comment: `,` is missing after `avatarMediaFileType`

Comment: You can also use `users.id` instead of `121` on the sub-querys so you don't have to repeat the id on every sub-query.